# IntelliJ IDEA / Scala: run configuration miss resources on class path

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, classpath

I have this problem on an off since quite while without ever understanding what is going on: I import an sbt-based project in IntelliJ, and when running it from within IntelliJ, it seems to be missing project resources (`src/main/resources`) on the class path, resulting in `.getClass.getResource(...)` calls to return `null`.
[image]

I tend to delete `.idea` and create the project anew as I'm suspecting a caching problem from upgrading an existing `.idea` from previous IntelliJ version. But no luck today. Sometimes changing `.getResource` to `.getResourceAsStream` seems to solve it, but again no luck today.

Checking the project settings, the directory is correctly toggled as 'Resources':

[image]

And checking the run configuration, the module/class-path is correctly selected:

[image]

Needless to say, using `sbt test:run` from the terminal works as expected, resources are found.

FWIF, here is the run call from IDEA, where I cannot find the resources in the classpath at all:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:47427,suspend=y,server=n -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/hhrutz/Documents/devel/Wolkenpumpe/target/scala-2.11/test-classes:/home/hhrutz/Documents/devel/Wolkenpumpe/target/scala-2.11/classes:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/com.github.scopt/scopt_2.11/jars/scopt_2.11-3.4.0.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.18.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.18.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.11/bundles/scalatest_2.11-2.2.6.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-stm/scala-stm_2.11/jars/scala-stm_2.11-0.7.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.11/bundles/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.5.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-swing_2.11/bundles/scala-swing_2.11-1.0.2.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.11.7.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.8.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/net.sourceforge.jtransforms/jtransforms/jars/jtransforms-2.4.0.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/net.htmlparser.jericho/jericho-html/jars/jericho-html-3.3.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/lucene/lucene/jars/lucene-1.4.3.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/junit/junit/jars/junit-4.8.2.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/weblaf-ui/2.1.0/jars/weblaf-ui.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/weblaf-core/2.1.0/jars/weblaf-core.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/treetable-scala_2.11/1.3.8/jars/treetable-scala_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/treetable-java/1.3.8/jars/treetable-java.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/topology_2.11/jars/topology_2.11-1.0.0.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/swingplus_2.11/0.2.1/jars/swingplus_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/submin/0.2.0/jars/submin.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/span_2.11/jars/span_2.11-1.3.1.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/soundprocesses-views_2.11/3.4.0/jars/soundprocesses-views_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/soundprocesses-core_2.11/3.4.0/jars/soundprocesses-core_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/serial_2.11/jars/serial_2.11-1.0.2.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/scissdsp_2.11/jars/scissdsp_2.11-1.2.2.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/scalaosc_2.11/1.1.5/jars/scalaosc_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/scalacolliderugens-plugins_2.11/1.14.1/jars/scalacolliderugens-plugins_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/scalacolliderugens-core_2.11/1.14.1/jars/scalacolliderugens-core_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/scalacolliderugens-api_2.11/1.14.1/jars/scalacolliderugens-api_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/scalacolliderswing-core_2.11/1.28.0/jars/scalacolliderswing-core_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/scalacollider_2.11/1.18.1/jars/scalacollider_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/scalaaudiofile_2.11/jars/scalaaudiofile_2.11-1.4.5.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/raphael-icons_2.11/1.0.3/jars/raphael-icons_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/processor_2.11/jars/processor_2.11-0.4.0.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/prefuse-core/1.0.1/jars/prefuse-core.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/numbers_2.11/jars/numbers_2.11-0.1.1.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/model_2.11/jars/model_2.11-0.3.2.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/lucresynth_2.11/3.4.0/jars/lucresynth_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/lucreswing_2.11/1.3.0/jars/lucreswing_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/lucre-expr_2.11/3.3.1/jars/lucre-expr_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/lucre-core_2.11/3.3.1/jars/lucre-core_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/lucre-confluent_2.11/3.3.1/jars/lucre-confluent_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/lucre-bdb_2.11/3.3.1/jars/lucre-bdb_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/intensitypalette/jars/intensitypalette-1.0.0.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/fingertree_2.11/jars/fingertree_2.11-1.5.2.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/de.sciss/fileutil_2.11/jars/fileutil_2.11-1.1.1.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/desktop_2.11/0.7.2/jars/desktop_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/audiowidgets-swing_2.11/1.9.4/jars/audiowidgets-swing_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/audiowidgets-core_2.11/1.9.4/jars/audiowidgets-core_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/local/de.sciss/audiowidgets-app_2.11/1.9.2/jars/audiowidgets-app_2.11.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream/jars/xstream-1.4.8.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/com.sleepycat/je/jars/je-5.0.104.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/com.mortennobel/java-image-scaling/jars/java-image-scaling-0.8.6.jar:/home/hhrutz/.ivy2/cache/com.jhlabs/filters/jars/filters-2.0.235.jar:/home/hhrutz/Applications/idea-IC-16/lib/idea_rt.jar de.sciss.nuages.Demo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the run configuration and creating it anew "fixed" the problem. It seems to be a bug in IntelliJ, perhaps related to caching or indexing.

The previous broken call was:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:47427,suspend=y,server=n \
  -classpath ... \
  de.sciss.nuages.Demo
```

The new correct call became:

```
java -Didea.launcher.port=7534 \
  -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/hhrutz/Applications/idea-IC-16/bin \
  -classpath ... \
  com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain de.sciss.nuages.Demo
```

So while the classpath is same, the launching mechanism is completely different.