# IntelliJ IDEA / Scala - cannot read resources

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, classpath

I have had this problem before, but it has been a while. Now it resurfaced: I am having an sbt-build based Scala project in IntelliJ IDEA, and when I launch a run config, the program does not find resources via `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`. It did work before, so definitely the paths in my code are correct. For example, here is a view of the project browser:

[image]

You can see that the `resources` directory is correctly marked, and so "/at/iem/sysson/color-tables.bin" should be found. Here is the reader code:

```
package at.iem.sysson

object Main {
  lazy val colorTables: Map[String, ColorPaletteTable] = {
    val is = Main.getClass.getResourceAsStream("color-tables.bin")
    ...
  }
}
```

This used to work in IntelliJ, it still works when running through `sbt` or creating a standalone application. But now with my run config from IntelliJ it is broken - `getResourceAsStream` returns `null`.

I have already deleted the `.idea` project and recreated it from scratch. I have also quit and restarted IntelliJ. The resources are definitely marked:

[image]

What's wrong? It looks related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664967/intellij-idea-scala-run-configuration-miss-resources-on-class-path), but deleting and recreating the run configuration does not help. I do get `/usr/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7537 ...`, but the `resources` directory is simply missing from the `-classpath`.

Comment: A work around is to use `src/main/resources` as working directory in run configuration.

Comment: What version are you using?  I had the same issue but believe it to be fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4, Build #IU-162.2032.8, built on September 9, 2016

Comment: @Matthew - yes, I'm using exactly that same version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same has just happened to me (IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.5).

When I looked into the `target/scala-2.11/classes` dir, the resource dirs/files were missing.

Just rebuilding the project didn't help, but **deleting** `target/scala-2.11/classes` and rebuilding did.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today.
At first, I tried to close the intelliJ, delete the `target` & `.idea` folders from Windows Explorer manually then reload the project in IntelliJ and then sbt update, sbt clean, and sbt compile. This did not help.

The second time, I did not close the IntelliJ, but just deleted the target dir from IntelliJ project explorer, and then I ran the main class, it threw classes not found exception because there was no target folder. Then `sbt compile` and run the main class. now it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).